# Decision tree algorithm for mixed numeric and nominal data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, decision-tree, id3

my dataset contains a number of numeric and categorical attributes

example: numericAttr1, numericAttr2, categoricalAttr1, numericalAttr3... where categoricalAttr values: categoricalAttrValue1, categoricalAttrValue2, categoricalAttrValue3.

i was thinking to convert numerical data into categorical data (using binning algorithm) and apply ID3 algorithm to produce tree because ID3 deals only with discrete data. but, how to handle overfitting? and also is it correct to categorise numerical data and apply ID3 algorithm?

Comment: Since this question is primarily about machine learning in general and not about a specific framework or coding problem, I suggest you ask it at http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If overfitting is a problem, and it is possible to replace your model, I would suggest using random forests as they are very much immune to overfitting.

Also you shouldn't be worried that the *binning* process will cause the overfitting as it creates a generalization of the data you have and if anything is more likely to reduce overfitting.

Answer (score 1):

There are several decision tree learners that can handle numerical attributes, e.g. C4.5 algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm).

Regarding overfitting, I agree with @ginge, the fact that you transform the numerical data to categorical with a technique such as binning shouldn't cause overfitting.